# Detect changes in a specific core data table

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, delegates, controller

I'm using a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to detect change in a table view that print "Events". But those "Events" are linked to an "Association", including a "isFollowed" number (if the `Assiciation.isFollow == 1`, then we print the event, otherwise we don't). We can change these isFollow BOOL, but the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate detect changes in "Events", not in "Association". So I'm using this code

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //[self setMyFetchedResultsController:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [myFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    [[self myTableView] reloadData];
}
```

to reload each time the table. The problem is that it is not very efficient, because it updates each time the controller, and not just when it's useful. So I wanted to know if there is a solution to detect changes in a specific row in a specific table in core data, or if you are thinking to a better way.

Thanks, Niels

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor save notifications (see NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotification docs) and crawl through their results to check if any Associations were changed. This approach is inherently inefficient.

A better approach though would probably be to have a delegate callback from the view controller modifying the association, and force the update of your table cell / fetched results controller after that.

I think it would appropriate in this instance to simply update the individual table cell representing the Event w/ the followed or unfollowed association. In the case of bulk updates though it would be best to simply reload the entire table.

Comment: and is there a way to get a hash code for the managedObject at a specific time ? For instance the code is 3. Then you made some changes, save them. Then the code is 4. And you update just when the codes are different. First I thought about using hasChange, but it is for uncommitted changed, and here I'm working with committed changes.

Comment: why isn't the presence in the NSUpdatedObjects portion of the save notification enough?